# How to use the query only vowels?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day.

I would like add a constraint on the vowels in the query.

Query:

```
SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE row LIKE '%$test__%'
```

where $test = 'test'(ex.) and `__` it only vowels:

1) if one `_` (`_`) that one vowels

2) if two `_` (`__`) that two vowels

Tell me please really and how make it in sql?

P.S.: example in result will be `SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE row LIKE '%testaa%'` or other two vowels after word `test`. result can not be `SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE row LIKE '%testab%'` ie can not have consonants after the word `test`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if one _ (_) that one vowels

   **SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE row LIKE '%$test[aeiou]%'**
2. if two _ (__) that two vowels

   **SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE row LIKE '%$test[aeiou][aeiou]%'**

Comment: can be if vowels on russian? ex. it will be [аоеи](example)

Comment: I think it will .. From MSDN ... `LIKE supports ASCII pattern matching and Unicode pattern matching. When all arguments (match_expression, pattern, and escape_character, if present) are ASCII character data types, ASCII pattern matching is performed. If any one of the arguments are of Unicode data type, all arguments are converted to Unicode and Unicode pattern matching is performed. `

Answer (score 0):

The T-SQL [LIKE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator supports some simple portions of regular expressions; namely character sets. You can update your query as follows to get results where a vowel immediately follows the word test:

`SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE row LIKE '%$test[aeiou]%'`

To determine whether multiple vowels followed, just repeat `[aeiou]` any number of times.

`SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE row LIKE '%$test[aeiou][aeiou][aeiou]%'`